# Behaviour of $i$ in polarization identity in complex Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-space, complex-numbers

I'm working through this video on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fjj6XNRtA40

But there's a step she makes that I don't understand, and when I try to do the proof myself I get stuck. This is what the video says:

$$ ||\Psi-i\Phi||^2 = ||\Psi||^2 + ||\Phi||^2 - \langle\Psi,-i\Phi\rangle - \langle -i\Phi,\Psi\rangle $$

She says that $ (-i\Phi)^2 $ turns into $ +||\Phi||^2 $ because $ i*i=-1 $ and that cancels the negative sign. As far as I know, the minus sign already cancels itself, so there is a triple minus sign and the expression should be:

$$ ||\Psi-i\Phi||^2 = ||\Psi||^2 - ||\Phi||^2 - \langle\Psi,-i\Phi\rangle - \langle -i\Phi,\Psi\rangle $$

Obviously i'm wrong, but what step am I missing?

edit: one more question. At one point she makes the step

$$ \langle\Psi,i\Phi\rangle = i\langle\Psi,\Phi\rangle $$

And I don't understand why that is not negative:

$$ \langle\Psi,i\Phi\rangle = -i\langle\Psi,\Phi\rangle $$

because of the property

$$ \langle x,y\rangle = \langle\ \overline{y,x}\rangle $$

I would say

$$ \langle x,iy\rangle = \langle\ \overline{iy,x}\rangle = \langle -iy,x\rangle = -i\langle y,x\rangle = -i\langle \overline{x,y}\rangle = -i\langle x,y\rangle $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\left<a\phi\mid b\psi\right>=a^{\ast}b\left<\phi\mid\psi\right>$$

Comment: Then i get $ ||\Psi-i\Phi||^2 = \langle\Psi-i\Phi,\Psi-i\Phi\rangle = \langle\Psi,\Psi\rangle + \langle -i\Phi,-i\Phi\rangle + \langle\Psi, -i\Phi\rangle + \langle -i\Phi,\Psi\rangle = \langle\Psi,\Psi\rangle - \langle \Phi,\Phi\rangle - i\langle\Psi,\Phi\rangle - i\langle \Phi,\Psi\rangle $ which is also not correct...

Comment: @enzolima I don't see how you get this. For example $\left<-i\Phi,-i\Phi\right>=\left(-i\right)^{\ast}\left(-i\right)\left<\Phi,\Phi\right>=\left<\Phi,\Phi\right>=\left\|\Phi\right\|^{2}$.

Comment: Well i get $ (-i)*(-i)=-1 $ which just follows the definition of i.

Comment: i'm sorry if i'm being particularly slow here, everywhere i look for this example your statement is being repeated as obviously correct but when i check in wolframalpha or google to be sure, (-i)*(-i)=-1 and i don't know where to place that in this example

Comment: @enzolima The operation $z^{\ast}$ is complex conjugation.

Comment: man everything just popped into place. thank you!